# "Pymongo" query for the field when array length greater than 0

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

For a collection nameed 'duplicate', we can execute `db.duplicate.find( { $where: "this.all_dups.length > 0" } );` but what would be the `Python` version of this query? I tried using

```
db.duplicate.find( { "$where": {"$gt":{"all_dups.length"} > 0] }} )
```

but it is showing me error for obvious reasons.

I also tried

```
db.duplicate.find( { "all_dups" : { "$size": { "$gt" : 0 }}})
```

I can do it in Python like:

```
for a in db.duplicate.find():
    if 'all_dups' in a and len(a['all_dups'])>0:
        print(a)
```

How can I achieve in `PyMongo`? I think there `$exists`, `$where`, `$gt` and `$size`  will be used but I don't exactly know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a search that excludes an empty list or a blank list:

```
db.duplicate.find({"all_dups": {'$nin': [[], None]}})
```